# How to JSON serialize an object and include the @property attributes while excluding functions?

Tags: python, json, properties

There are quite a few questions related to this but non gives me exactly what I want.

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
import json


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, name, some_type):

        self.name = name
        self.some_type = some_type

    @property
    def prop(self):

        return self.name + self.some_type

    def to_json(self):

        return json.dumps(
            self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__
        )


el1 = MyClass('test', '_to_json')
```

I would now like to get a JSON representation which includes `name`, `some_type` and also `prop`.

The function `to_json` currently only returns

```
{"name": "test", "some_type": "_to_json"}
```

so `prop` is missing (as well as in `vars(el1)`).

`dir` returns (as well as all the `__`)

```
'name', 'prop', 'some_type', 'to_json'
```

and I don't want the `to_json` in the list.

Is there a straightforward way to update my `to_json` function so that it returns

```
{"name": "test", "some_type": "_to_json", "prop": "test_to_json"}
```

?

Comment: What's wrong with `json.dumps({"name": self.name, "some_type": self.some_type, "prop": self.prop})`? Be explicit. Or `json.dumps({k: getattr(self, k) for k in ["name", "prop", "some_type"]})`.

Comment: @chepner: True, this will work, but then I would have to change this function everytime I add a new `@property` which I would like to avoid (should have stated this in the questions).

Comment: That's a fairly minor change on top of what you need to do to add the property in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `prop` in `__class__.__dict__`:

```
import json


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, name, some_type):

        self.name = name
        self.some_type = some_type

    @property
    def prop(self):

        return self.name + self.some_type

    def to_json(self):
        def get_object_dict(obj):
            d = obj.__dict__.copy()
            for key, value in obj.__class__.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(value, property):
                    d[key] = getattr(obj, key)
            return d


        return json.dumps(
            self, default=lambda o: get_object_dict(o)
        )


el1 = MyClass('test', '_to_json')
print(el1.to_json())
```

Output:

```
{"prop": "test_to_json", "some_type": "_to_json", "name": "test"}
```